# Cookie stealing

Tags: php, cookies

I have read many answers on stackoverflow, but none of them could answer my question.
Let's consider a case, where a teacher and the student use the same computer. The teacher uses it to upload marks and the student use the computer to browse the marks. Now, the cookies of the teacher are stored and accessible. The student can easily forge the cookies and present himself as a teacher to the system and create havoc.
What approach should I take to disable this? Is this only possible via sessions? Or there exists a possibility with cookies as well.

Comment: You delete the session when the teacher logs out, then the cookie becomes a useless value.

Comment: Cookies are typically stored per-user in a protected manner. A teacher and a student may share a computer but they shouldn't be using the same account on it. Beyond that, have sessions expire fairly quickly - 15-20 min.

Comment: Ok, so what if after the teacher logs out, I access his cookies someway and then present myself as the teacher?

Comment: @Akshay Logging out renders the cookies useless. Typically, the cookie contains only a session ID - the sensitive data is stored on the server. When they log out, you delete the session data so the cookie is not usable anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The main two suggestions I would have are:

1. Delete the entire session right before the user logs out or logs in. A new session should always be started when authorization level changes.
2. Only accept sessions ids *you* generate. By default PHP will accept and start a new session for any value of the session id you send it. If you receive a session id you haven't seen before, discard it and send the user a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not necessary to have the browser remeber the cookie between browser sessions (eg a login can be 'forgotten' if the browser window is closed), then you could NOT set the expiry date on the cookie which makes it memory-resident only.

When the user closes the web broswer, the cookie is forgotten (standard browser behaviour) so there's no link to the old session, and a new login must be provided. The old session becomes "orphaned" and (assuming you have a 'expire through inactivity' process) will be expired eventually.

If you need the browser to remember the last user even if the window was closed, then a short-but-appropriate timeout is needed - destroy the session making the cookie useless after x minutes/hours inactivity (whatever is appropriate).